# Reject changes out of bound range on DoubleProperty

Tags: java, javafx, properties

I was recently trying to constrain the range my double property to `(0.0 - 1.0)`. Changes out of this range shouln't have any effect, or throw an error.

Currently I did it with either 2 ways:

- Read only, and changes allowed on accesors only:

  ```
  private ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper numProperty = new ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper(0);

  public final double getNum() {
      return numProperty().get();
  }

  public final void setNum(double num) {
      if(num < 0)
          num = 0;
      if(num > 1)
          num = 1;
      numProperty.set(num);
  }

  public ReadOnlyDoubleProperty numProperty() {
      return numProperty.getReadOnlyProperty();
  }
  ```
- Setting listeners to reset value:

  ```
  private DoubleProperty numProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);
  numProperty.addListener(new BoundRangeListener(numProperty, 0.0, 1.0));


  class BoundRangeListener implements ChangeListener<Number> {

      Property<Number> prop;
      double min, max;

      BoundRangeListener(Property<? extends Number> prop, double min, double max) {
          this.prop = prop;
          this.min = min;
          this.max = max;
      }

      public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> o,
                                           Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
          if(newValue.doubleValue() < min)
              prop.set(min);
          if(newValue.doubleValue() > max)
              prop.set(max);

          // Optional: throw exception
      }

  }
  ```

Still, I'm not comfortable with neither of these solutions. The first won't allow my users to bind the property; not something I want, without a good reason. The second would fire 2 events to other listeners; no good.

So my question: Is there any out-of-the-box way to reject a change, or bound the number property to a range?

Comment: I would refactor the first solution using a [`ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper.html) in place of the `DoubleProperty`, with the `numProperty()` method returning `numProperty.getReadOnlyProperty()`. You could also consider subclassing `SimpleDoubleProperty` and overriding the `set(...)` and `setValue(...)` methods. (Kind of hard to actually answer this though, unless you say why you're not comfortable with the solutions you have.)

Comment: Overriding... Didn't think of _this_... +1. Post it as answer.

Comment: Edited, why I'm not comfortable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider subclassing `SimpleDoubleProperty` and overriding the `set` and `setValue` methods:

```
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;

public class ClampedDoublePropertyTest {

    private DoubleProperty numProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0) {

        @Override
        public void set(double value) {

            System.out.println("set("+value+")");
            if (value < 0) {
                value = 0 ;
            }
            if (value > 1) {
                value = 1 ;
            }
            super.set(value);
        }

        @Override
        public void setValue(Number value) {
            System.out.println("setValue("+value+")");
            if (value == null) {
                // depending on requirements, throw exception, set to default value, etc.
            } else {
                if (value.doubleValue() < 0) {
                    value = new Double(0);
                }
                if (value.doubleValue() > 1) {
                    value = new Double(1);
                }
                super.setValue(value);
            }
        }

    };

    public DoubleProperty numProperty() {
        return numProperty;
    }

    public final double getNum() {
        return numProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setNum(double num) {
        numProperty().set(num);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClampedDoublePropertyTest test = new ClampedDoublePropertyTest();
        test.numProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> System.out.println(oldValue +" -> "+newValue));

        DoubleProperty value = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        test.numProperty().bind(value);
        value.set(0.5);
        value.set(2);
        value.set(-5);
    }
}
```

This will allow client code to bind the property in the usual way:

```
myInstance.numProperty().bind(...);
```

though note that this will violate the usual binding contract, as if the observable value to which it is bound is out of range, the two values will not be equal.

As an aside, FWIW Oracle [recommend](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/javafx-2-prog-model-1524061.pdf) (slide 29) the listener approach, though I agree with you that I don't like it (particularly as it allows an observer to observe an "invalid value").

Comment: Or instead of violating binding contract, I could throw an exception. (Like it would, if you tried to bind a bound property).

Comment: Yes, that would be an option too. However, I don't think that would veto the change to the property to which it was bound, so you would still end up with the properties out of sync...

Comment: No, the program crashing.

Comment: What about bindBidirectional(), do I have to override it too?

Comment: Ah, hmm. I hadn't thought about that... I'd need to test it and I'm not at the computer right now.

Comment: Side note: use Double.valueOf or autoboxing instead of new Double.

Comment: Is overriding the bind method needed? I think overriding the two set methods should be enough. Maybe even only the setValue method.

Comment: @Puce. I thought overriding bind would not be necessary, but in testing it appeared that bind does not call either set method. Assuming setValue calls set (which is not documented) is risky at best - I haven't tested if that works though.

Comment: @James_D It only invalidates the property, but will call `setValue()` when asked by listener, I think.

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented a [LimitedComparableProperty](http://www.drombler.org/drombler-commons/0.7/docs/site/apidocs/org/drombler/commons/fx/beans/property/LimitedComparableProperty.html). Maybe you find it useful.

```
double minValue = 0;
double maxValue = 1;
LimitedComparableProperty<Double> numProperty = new LimitedComparableProperty<>(this, "numProperty", 0, minValue , maxValue);
```

Note: Currently only [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)s are supported, no primitive types. (you would have to use Double instead of double).

Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drombler.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>drombler-commons-fx-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.7</version>
</dependency>
```

The code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/Drombler/drombler-commons/blob/develop/drombler-commons-fx/drombler-commons-fx-core/src/main/java/org/drombler/commons/fx/beans/property/LimitedComparableProperty.java).

Comment: Sounds like exactly what I need. Will look into it and maybe accept this answer.

Comment: Implementing a property implementation from scratch it almost certainly the way to go for this.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do this would be to do something like this:

```
Math.max(min, Math.min(val, max));
```

This should make any number less than the minimum value (0.0) be set to the minimum value, and any number greater than the maximum value (1.0) be set to the maximum value.

Comment: I understand, that wasn't my question. Queston is, how do I inject it in my property?

Comment: It is a JavaFX specific question.